# Convex functions -> quasi-convex functions -> ... can we weaken the assumptions?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

First of all let me say that I'm new to optimization. I realized that quasi-convex functions share with convex functions some nice properties, so I wonder if we can push the weakening a little further.
We all know that quasi-convex functions are functions whose sublevel sets are convex. What if we try to build an optimization theory for objective functions whose sublevel sets are...

- bounded
- simply connected
- star-shaped
- combinations of above... or anything else.

I'm curious if is there a direction that lead to satisfactory results. Ok, nothing can compare to convex optimization, but some results for more general functions may be interesting. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing continuous functions over compact level-sets is a nice problem.

Boundedness of level-sets alone is not enough. The function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1-x^2 & |x|<1\\
x^2 & |x|\ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
has bounded level sets, but there exists no global minimizer.

The function $f(x)=e^x$ has star-shaped, connected level-sets, but no minimizer exists.

Comment: Thank you very much daw!
Any references about minimization of continuous functions with compact level sets?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem